# Stratified Sampling in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, qubole

The following returns a `10%` sample of the `A` and `X` columns stratified by the values of `X`.

```
  select A, X from(
  select A, 
      count(*) over (partition by X) as cnt, 
      rank() over (partition by X order by rand()) as rnk
      from my_table) table 
  where rnk <= cnt*0.1
```

In other words, if `X` takes the values `[X0, X1]` it returns the union of:

- 10% of the the rows where `X = X0`
- 10% of the the rows where `X = X1`

How can I stratify my query by values of **tuples** for several columns (e.g. `X`, `Y`)?

For example, if `X` takes values `[X0, X1]` and Y takes values `[Y0, Y1]`, I would like to get a sample that is the union of:

- 10% of the the rows where `X = X0` and `Y=Y0`
- 10% of the the rows where `X = X0` and `Y=Y1`
- 10% of the the rows where `X = X1` and `Y=Y0`
- 10% of the the rows where `X = X1` and `Y=Y1`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use your method above, but use a hash of the columns you'd like to consider.